# Remove control charaters from JavaScript string

Tags: javascript

```
[24;1H[K[13;1H[K[0m[0m[13;1HSelect option (1-8)[0m[13;30H[K[0m[0m[13;30H1[0m[0m[1m[4m[7m[1;60H  **AMEND/CREATE**  [0m[2;1H[J[4;1H[K[0m[1m[4;1HMenu Number[0m
```

How can you remove the control charaters from the above string?

the text is meant to read

```
Select option (1-8) 1

  **AMEND/CREATE**  

Menu Number
```

Comment: Can you post the code you've got so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a regular expression to replace anything that starts with `[` and ends with `H` or `m`.

```js
var stream = "[24;1H[K[13;1H[K[0m[0m[13;1HSelect option (1-8)[0m[13;30H[K[0m[0m[13;30H1[0m[0m[1m[4m[7m[1;60H  **AMEND/CREATE**  [0m[2;1H[J[4;1H[K[0m[1m[4;1HMenu Number[0m";

var cleaned = stream.replace(/\[.*?[Hm]/g, '');
console.log(cleaned);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can remove control characters by using a regular expression (as a range of octal characters). See if the following works for you. If it misses any character, let me know, I can add it.

```
var s = '<' + 'H' + '\010' +  'E' + '\011' + 'L' + '\012' + 'L' + '\013' + 'O' + '\014' + '>';
console.log(s);
s=s.replace(/[\010-\017]/g,"");
console.log(s);
```